# How to copy values between 8087 ST(0) and ST(i) registers?

Tags: fpu, x87

To copy from ST(0) to ST(i), I've figured out that `fst ST(i)` works.

How do I copy values from ST(i) to ST(0), without affecting other ST(...) registers or the stack? I could come up with `fxch ST(i)` followed by `fst ST(i)`. Is there a single-instruction version?

Answer (score 0):

More Google searches haven't revealed single-instruction solution, so it's only `fxch` + `fst`. The instruction `fld` is not relevant, it isn't able to copy between two registers without touching other registers (as part of the stack).

Thus:

- To copy from ST(0) to ST(i), use `fst ST(i)`.
- To copy from ST(i) to ST(0), use `fxch ST(i)` followed by `fst ST(i)`.
- To copy from ST(i) to ST(j), use `fxch ST(i)` followed by `fst ST(j)` followed by `fxch ST(i)`.
- To swap ST(0) and ST(i), use `fxch ST(i)`.
- To swap ST(i) and ST(j) if j != 0, use `fxch ST(i)` followed by `fxch ST(j)` followed by `fxch ST(i)`.